How do I interprety multi variable graphs in R
I'm having an issue with reading the plot that emerged from my dataset.  At first glance I thought it was very obvious but I do not understand the diagonal among these plots.
All the other charts make sense to me.  The top right section refers to the correlation between variables so sodas sold and working ovens has a correlation of .009.  The bottom left section contains actual plots, so the very bottom left chart represents the amount of working ovens and sodas sold on a certain day.
This reasoning doesn't really apply though for the diagonal of charts.  If I'm plotting working ovens against working ovens shouldnt I just have a straight y=x plot. Instead all of these charts are curves.  What do these charts actually represent?
Image of the plots I generate

The boxes along the diagonals display the density plot for each variable. A density plot is a representation of the distribution of a numeric variable. It uses a kernel density estimate to show the probability density function of the variable. Think of it as a smoothed version of the histogram and is used in the same concept. Density plots are used to study the distribution of one or a few variables. Checking the distribution of your variables one by one is probably the first task you should do when you get a new dataset. It delivers a good quantity of information. Checking this distribution also helps you discovering mistakes in the data. Learn more about Density Plots here:

https://r-graph-gallery.com/density-plot.html
https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/histograms-and-density.html
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-a-scatter-plot-matrix-in-r/

Smoothed Version of Histogram Example (Look at the diagonals):

